# How to run recorded automation scripts on robot framework RIDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, katalon-recorder

I have recorded some action on a website by using Katalon  Automation recorder. Then, I export test cases as scripts format (robot framework) and save it. I want to run recorded scripts on robot framework  RIDE. Thank you in advance. Is it possible? or any recorder tool to record it and then run it on robot framework RIDE?

***Note Katalon  Automation recorder, record scripts as command "Click" or "Open".Although there is no "Click" or "Open" keyword on robot framework.

[image]

Comment: You can create with google chrome extension: Selenium Page Object Generator. Then you can run it, like python file.

Comment: Have you tried the conversion robot file that can be downloaded from [https://github.com/ngocbv/Robot-Framework-Formatter/](https://github.com/ngocbv/Robot-Framework-Formatter/blob/master/resources/seleniumLibrary.robot) that converts these Katalon keywords to Robot Keywords.

Comment: @A Kootstra, Thank you - Selenium IDE: RobotFramework Formatter add-on is not compatible with  Firefox browser version:60.Attachment image as https://www.screencast.com/t/Cv2SovPH .Also I am unable to go as step-3  Export to Robot Framework format
File -> Export Test Case As... -> Robot Framework formatter
Please Advise.